# difference between useradd -b and useradd -d

Tags: linux, debian, options, useradd

Can somebody please explain to me the exact differences between `useradd -b` and `useradd -d` in [Debian] Linux? Both seem to work quite similar to me, but then I spot differences that confuse me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-b` specifies the location of users' home directories.  On your average Debian box, this will be `/home`; you can change the default by editing `/etc/default/useradd`.  `useradd` will add the new username to this path to get the home directory.  This means that if you do

```
useradd -b /somewhere ian
```

the new user's directory will be `/somewhere/ian`.

`-d` sets the home directory explicitly, irrespective of defaults.  So

```
useradd -d /somewhere-else/ian ian
```

then the user's home directory will be set to `/somewhere-else/ian`.

Note that the directory will be set in the password file, but won't actually be created unless `-m` is also specified (or the `CREATE_HOME` setting is enabled in the defaults file).

Comment: Your explanation is (mostly) correct, but to better stress the difference between the switches, you could have used something other than "ian" as the home directory in the `-d` example. That's the main point of using `-d` rather than `-b`. Also, in the `-d` example you're missing the username, so that command wouldn't work.

Comment: Oops, I fixed my typo, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: In connection with the `-m` option - the difference between `-b` and `-d` is that `-d` allows to set an actual name, possibly differing from the user's name [e.g. `/somewhere/ians_new_home`] and that `-b` creates a new directory with the user's name [`/somewhere/ian` as you already described :) ]`.

Using neither `-b` nor `-d` [in connection with `-m`] will create a new user with a home directory in `/home`.
Could this really have been all that is about that difference? Another case of 'overseen because too obvious?'